# Django: Can I prevent logged in users from accessing login.html?

Tags: python, django, authentication, passwords

I have two general questions:

1. As per the title, is there a way to make users who have an active session running that try to access /login.html be routed to /home.html instead?
2. I'm using Django's default PasswordChangeForm and when a user changes their password, it lets them use their old password. So this works:

Old Password: 123456

New Password: 123456

Repeat New Password: 123456

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details on the second question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want to let them input their current password as a new password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, assuming that you serve the `/login.html` through a View, you can easily check if the user is logged in and in that case serve a 302 redirect like this.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/home.html')
```

Full documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-raw-way

Comment: Wouldn't it be:  
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('/home.html')?